# react-native run-android --variant release fails to load updated bundle

Tags: android, react-native

When ever I make any changes and run the app in `release mode` by running following command,

```
react-native run-android --variant release
```

The installed app will not have new changes. Then I will run app in `debug mode` by running following command,

```
react-native run-android
```

Then I will be able to see all the changes. Now If i run release command i.e `react-native run-android --variant release` then I will be able to see new chnages.

That being said, every time I make any changes in code, first I will have to run in `debug mode` then only I can see those changes in `release mode`.

1.What to do If I have to see the new changes in `release mode` without running in `debug mode`?

**Note:** Recently, I have accidentally deleted `.android` folder. Then I completely deleted `Android Studio` and installed once again. Since then I am facing the above issue.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. On my end it will not build new changes even if I do a debug build first. Did you find a fix for this?